# How to get the url resource path match in node.js express?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get png image by path like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/image/line.png
```

how do I write the `app.get()` function to match the path and get the filename, then read the file in location and return it?
I am new to express in node.js.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#route-paths

Comment: take a look at the [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) api. hope this will provide you with some sort of direction. good luck!

Comment: @jkris it solves my question, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ExpressJS 4.0. You can do it by my example below:

```
app.get('/image/:fileName', function(req ,res) {
    var path = require('path');
    var file = path.join(PATH_TO_IMAGE_DIRECTORY, req.params.fileName);
    res.sendFile(file);
});
```

Please make note that you should change PATH_TO_IMAGE_DIRECTORY by your image directory location. For example: `__dirname, '../upload'`

I shared a full post about upload and get the uploaded images with nodejs and expressjs 4.0: [HOW TO UPLOAD FILES WITH NODEJS AND EXPRESSJS 4](https://sonnguyen.ws/how-to-upload-files-with-nodejs-and-expressjs-4/)